# Undefined offset :0 ..., While that's defined

Tags: php, arrays

I wrote a code like this in a function:

```
preg_match_all('/{ali\s+([^}\s]+)\s*}/', $row->text, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
$m=$matches[0][1];
```

When I write this:

```
$row->text=$m;
```

It returns the value (for example "name" in "{ali name}" and "id" in "{ali id}"),but when I write this:

```
$a->name='hasan';
$a->id='14';
$row->text=$a->$m;
```

It says:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in ... on line 2
```

What's the problem?! I tested existance of spaces,tabs,etc in the string but there was not any of them!

Comment: Replace `$row->text=$a->$m;` with `$row->text=$a->m;`

Comment: Well do a `print_r($matches)` to see the structure of the array, and based on the result you construct further your code. Simple.

Comment: Please rename the title. When what is defined?

Comment: I did print_r($matches), that exist. I said it returns my string when I use $row->text=$m;

Comment: Should `$row->text=$a->$m;` not be `$row->text=$a->m;` or `$row->text=$a->name.' '.$a->id;`

Comment: @user1904238 ok, provide the **full** code you're using and tell us on which line you get the error. From what you have written, the error is on line 2 which means `$m=$matches[0][1];` is triggering the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `isset()` checking

```
if(isset($matches[0][1])){
//Code here
}
```

Comment: Or better still, check the return value of `preg_match_all`.

Comment: I know that exists! It returns my string when I use $row->text=$m;

Comment: Try print_r($matches) and check whther $matches[0] or $matches[0][1] exists or not after the preg_match()

Comment: I,ve tried print_r($matches), yes, they exist!

Comment: It's just impossible that the index exists and you get an undefined offset error. Get real.

Comment: The problem was that my function was operating in various places in the page but I wasn't know that! Thank you all